# Updating shopping cart

Tags: asp-classic

i am using this code to remove items from my shopping cart

```
     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox" onClick="document.form2.txtQTY<%if        (UCCart1.GetItemCount()<>1) Then Response.Write("["& UCCart1__i& "]")%>.value='0'"/>
```

when i click the check box the item quantity in the cart turns to zero. i have a update button as well which removes the item when the checkbox is checked. how can i stop the value from changing to zero. i just want the quantity to remain the same and when i click update cart the item is removed.

i am new to this so any help will be appreciated

Comment: This looks more like a JavaScript question - The ASP code there does its stuff on the server as the page is being generated in the first place

Comment: Removing the onclick part of this will stop it setting the quantity to zero, but you will need to add code server side to remove the item when the checkbox is checked.